# My profile picture is not taken from gravatar

Tags: support, gravatar

I have a gravatar, had it for a long time now. My stackoverflow user does not show that picture. It works fine in other websites. I have the correct email. Changing the gravatar image does not help either.

Why isn't stackoverflow showing my gravatar?

Comment: I have the same issue I can't get it to show up is there a way to debug the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using an X-rated image, you dirty boy!

[image: the filthy X-rated version - flag as offensive!]

> https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/40656706454dcbdbcec125b85b01f1e4?s=128&d=identicon**&r=x**

I don't know why [you rated it that way](http://en.gravatar.com/site/check), but you should know that Stack Overflow is a family website, and will only display G or PG-rated [gravatars](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/url):

[image: the PG version]

> https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/40656706454dcbdbcec125b85b01f1e4?s=128&d=identicon**&r=PG**

Comment: "Stack Overflow is a family website" really?

Comment: Families just ain't what they used to be...

Comment: No, I think Jeff was confused because Stack Overflow is a family of websites. The wording is really quite similar.

Comment: it's because Ninjas are so awesome THEY SHOULD BE RATED X FOR XXXXTREME!!

Comment: lol, it's actually a snowboarding mask :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Shog9 You better hope he never actually uploads an X-rated image to be used as a gravatar for that email account. You'll have put porn on meta.  ;)

Answer (score 7):

1. Make sure that the email in your profile matches the email you are using for gravatar (or include the new email on your gravatar account).
2. You may have to wait a short period. It tends to take a little while for a gravatar image to be fetched and cached by StackOverflow.

Comment: And don't forget Ctrl-F5

Comment: The email matches, and I've waited forever (is half a year enough?)

Comment: I'd wait a few more months before you decide if it's *really* a problem

Comment: Well, it's really a problem for me - my gravatar is not updated!

Comment: This is a problem for me too.  I only recently setup my gravatar account.  I have a G-rated image and verified the emails match.

Comment: My innocuous gravatar also fails to show up.  However, I have only waited 30 hours since creating it.

Comment: As for me, email matches gravatar email and I've waited for a long time. So, it is obviously a bug in stackoverflow.